# Does qmake support running sanity checks on project dependencies?

Tags: qmake, build-system

I'm working on a legacy Qt project which relies heavily on qmake, and I've experienced a fair share of subtle build errors which could be easily avoided with some sanity checks, such as verifying if a library or a file is actually where it's expected to be.

Does anyone know if qmake supports running sanity checks at the prebuild stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qmake supports test functions which can be used to test preconditiosn.  See qmake manual's page on [test functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html).